# Any other software to put music in iphone

Tags: iphone

Is there any other software to put mp3 on iphone.
I need to connect iphone to several computer but evrytime it says that if you syc you data will be erased.

I only want to add music nothing else.

What should i do

Answer (score 1):

You can add music with iTunes without syncing:

- In the **Library** list in the left-hand column click on **Music**
- On the right hand side, go to the music you added to the iTunes Library that you want on your iPhone
- Drag the album or song onto your iPhone listing under **Devices** in the left-hand column
- Wait for the **iPod Sync is complete** message (even though you haven't used Sync)
- Click on **Eject iPod** and wait for the **do not disconnect** message
- Disconnect the cable and you're new song or album should be added.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this problem is to set up iTunes on each computer so that you can sync with all of them.

[How To Sync Your iPhone To Multiple Computers](http://www.ismashphone.com/2009/05/how-to-sync-your-iphone-to-multiple-computers.html)